# Display Angular Loading Bar in a specific $http request NOT in the whole module

Tags: angularjs, loading

When I used the chieffancypants loadingBar, the loading bar appears from the start of the loading of the page and to every $http request that i make,

I want to display only the loading bar progress when I click the search button which retrieves a large amount of data.

```
var mtg = angular.module('mtgApp',['ui.bootstrap','chieffancypants.loadingBar','ngAnimate']);

mtg.controller('mtgController',function($scope,$http,$location)
{
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://sampleAPIURL.com";
    $scope.token = "sampletoken";
    $scope.processForm = function()
    {
       $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: apiBaseUrl + 'flight/search?token=' + $scope.token,
                data: {       
                          //my json request
                          //flightForm.from,
                          //flightForm.to,
                          //flightForm.date
                      }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.displayResults(data.searchId);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                console.log("Check For Errors");                
            });
    }

    $scope.displayResults = function(searchId)
    {
       $http.get(apiBaseUrl + 'Flight/results/'+searchId+'?$top=50&token=' + $scope.token).success(function(data)
       {
            $scope.results = data.flightResult;
            $location.path('/search/results');
       });
    };
});
```

In my search

```
<form ng-controller = "mtgController">
     <input type = "text" ng-model = "flightForm.from">
     <!--uses $http request to get the suggested location-->

     <input type = "text" ng-model = "flightForm.to">
     <!--uses $http request to get the suggested location-->

     <input type = "text" ng-model = "flightForm.date">
     <input type = "button" ng-click = "processForm()" value = "Search">
</form>
```

In my html search/results

```
<form>
    <div ng-controller = "mtgController">
        <div ng-repeat = "result in results">
            //{{result.details}} and so on and so on
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want the loading bar appears only when I click the search button while waiting for the response data and go to the results page

Comment: were you able to achieve what you were looking for? If yes can you please share it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add after data:

```
        success: function (test) {
            $("#mtg.controller").val('');
            $("#success").html(test);
            $("#mtg.controller").removeClass("disabled");

        }
     });

 });
```

});

Also, you can do `success: function` instead of `succes(function` for what you already have.

Comment: do this instead of your current success